# When using docker run, how do I specify whether I intend to use a named volume or a bind mount?

Tags: docker, containers, volumes

Given the following command `docker run -v value-a:some/dir my-image`, will docker mount a volume named `value-a` or mount the directory `value-a` found on the host machine? How does docker run differentiate between volumes and bind mounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind mount paths *have* to be absolute on the `docker run` command, so in your case, it'll create a volume since `value-a` isn't an absolute path. To have it bind to the directory, you'd use something like

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/value-a:some/dir my-image
```